# Bound ComboBoxItem not displaying

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `ComboBox` used for selecting a file, and based on the user requiremenst the full path should be displayed in the `ComboBox`, whereas only the filename (minus directory) should be shown in the selectable items. I'm following the MVVM pattern, and the `ComboBox` is bound to an instance of type `FileInfo` in the ViewModel, where there is also an `ObservableCollection<FileInfo>` that becomes the `ItemsSource`. The current XAML for this is like so:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding FilePath}" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableFiles}">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Name="FilePathText" Text="{Binding FullName}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
         <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False">
               <Setter TargetName="FilePathText" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="{x:Null}">
               <Setter TargetName="FilePathText" Property="Text" Value="{Binding FullName}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </DataTemplate.Triggers>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The problem is, even though the default value for `FilePath` is a selectable item in the `ItemsSource`, and is bound properly (I've used Christian Moser's WPF Inspector to check the DataSource when the application starts), the `ComboBox` shows nothing until a value is selected. What is causing this? Since that `ComboBoxItem's` `IsSelected` property is null, it should be displaying the `FullName` of the `FileInfo` object.

Any help given would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is ItemsSource populated at the point the view is created?

Comment: Actually, no; the selection of files is calculated and a message published using an event aggregator which the ViewModel subscribes to; however, when it changes, the PropertyChanged event is raised for all the affected bound properties.

Comment: I've found ComboBox has a tendency to null the SelectedItem when it isn't within the ItemsSource. Can you set the SelectedItem after ItemsSource is populated.

Comment: Yeah, you guided me towards fixing it, thanks! Add this as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `SelectedItem` is not contained within `ItemsSource` at the point of binding, then `ComboBox` has a nasty habit of setting `SelectedItem` back to null.

Try and hold off updating `SelectedItem` until `ItemsSource` is populated.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are doing you may want to use SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath. This is what I did and  it works for me.

I did this in code but this should still work with Binding.
In C#:

```
  availableFiles.Add(new FileInfo(@"Program.cs"));
  filebox.ItemsSource = availableFiles;
  filebox.SelectedValue = new FileInfo(@"Program.cs");
  filebox.SelectedValuePath = "FullName";
```

and my combobox is template

```
 <ComboBox  Name="filebox">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Name="FilePathText" Text="{Binding FullName}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="FilePathText" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="FilePathText" Property="Text" Value="{Binding FullName}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

In your case

```
 <ComboBox  Name="filebox" SelectedValue="{Binding FileInfoObject}" SelectedValuePath ="FullName">
```

Update This works

```
<ComboBox  Name="filebox" SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding FileInfoObject}"  ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableFiles}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Name="FilePathText"  TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="FilePathText" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="FilePathText" Property="Text" Value="{Binding FullName}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="FilePathText" Property="Text" Value="{Binding FullName}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: This is causing some really strange behaviour; the combo box has a red outline to show error, and when values are selected they revert to previous selections.

Comment: Is SelectedValue a FileInfoObject? It isn't the FilePath that you were previously binding to.

Comment: I know what the problem is. There is no coversion from Name string or fullName string in the Datatriggers